# REACT - Turn a selection from a dropdown to a tag label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Is there a way to turn a selection from a dropdown to a tag  with the appropriate color (see the image).

ItemDisplay.jsx

```
export default function ItemDisplay() {
...
  const colourStyles = {
    singleValue: (provided, { data }) => ({
      ...provided,
      backgroundColor:
        data.value === "Good"
          ? "#36B37E"
          : data.value === "Medium"
          ? "#FF8B00"
          : data.value === "Bad"
          ? "#FF5630"
          : ""
    })
  };
...
  return (
      ...
          <Dropdown
            style={styles.select}
            options={TASTE}
            defaultValue={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === item.taste)}
            styleSelect={colourStyles}
          />
        </div> 
       ...      
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use a diffrent component for tag and switch between by setting selected as a state.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "switch between by setting selected as a state"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is having another Tag component that replace the dropdown each time you select an element:

```
export default function CustomDropdown({
  style,
  options,
  styleSelect,
  defaultValue
}) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(defaultValue);
  const backgroundColor = styleSelect?.(selected?.label) ?? "grey";
  
  const Tag = () => {
    return (
      <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent:"space-around", padding: "0.2em",backgroundColor: backgroundColor, borderRadius: "2px", color:"white"}}>
        {selected.label}
        <button
        style={{backgroundColor: "transparent", color:"white", border: "none", cursor: "pointer"}} 
        onClick={() => setSelected(null)}>x</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      {selected ?
       <Tag />
       :
      <Select
        value={selected}
        onChange={setSelected}
        options={options}
      />
      }
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Ideally you should create a proper file for the Tag component and pass the **selected** prop to the component.

Also I changed the implementation of **colourStyles** and made it a function that returns the proper color based on the selection:

```
const colourStyles = (selected) => {
     switch(selected){
       case "Good": 
        return "#36B37E";
       case "Medium": 
        return "#FF8B00";
       case "Bad": 
        return "#FF5630";
       default:
         return ""
     }
  };
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried to create a proper file with the `Tag` component but the colors don't work, and I can't change the value. Everything is fixed [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-z37eu1?file=/src/MenuItemDisplay.jsx)

Comment: That's because you created the state inside the Tag component. You should have passed <Tag selected={selected} setSelected={setSelected} styleSelect={styleSelect}  /> and use the props from the parent. Otherwise just copy paste my code and you will see that it works.

Comment: hi can you help me with this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72398235/default-value-with-react-select-and-condition-are-not-working-used-to-work-on) please ? I'm now using data from api in my CustromDropdown but doesn't seem working (maybe because I use array )