# Default value with react-select, checkboxes not working when I want to post my data having a blank page output

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-select

I'm not able to put my fetch data as a defaultValue in my Dropdown (react-select) and Checkboxe? I have the displayed dropdown ("Good",...) but the defaultValue for the `dishId:1` is `Medium`, so I'm supposed to see Medium already selected in my Dropdown, which is not the case (same issue for comment).

```
export default function MenuItemDisplay() {
...
    const [dish, setDish] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post(url, { dishId })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setDish(res.data.dishes [0])
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [dishId]);

    const TASTE = [
        { label: "Good", value: "Good" },
        { label: "Medium", value: "Medium" },
        { label: "Bad", value: "Bad" }
    ];
    const COMMENT = [
        { label: "0", value: "0" },
        ...
    ];


function Checkbox({ value }) {
    const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);

    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          defaultChecked={checked}
          onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        />
        {value}
      </label>
    );
  }    

    return (
        <>
            <Dropdown
                style={styles.select}
                options={TASTE}
                defaultValue={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === dish.taste)}
                isMulti={true}
            />
           <Dropdown
                    style={styles.select}
                    options={COMMENT}
                    defaultValue={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === dish.comment)}
                    isMulti={true}
                />
           <Checkbox value={!!dish.trust} />

            {(dish.menu) !== "") ?
                <div>
                    Menu
                    <div >
                        {dish.menu}
                    </div>
                </div>
                : ""
            }
        </>
    );
}


export default function CustomDropdown({
    className,
    style,
    options,
    styleSelect,
    value,
    setValue,
    isMulti = false
}) {
    const styles = {
        select: {
            width: "100%",
            maxWidth: 200
        }
    };

    function changeSelect(option) {
        setValue(option.value);
    }

    return (
        <div style={style} onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
            {value && isMulti === false ? (
                <Tag
                    selected={value}
                    setSelected={setValue}
                    styleSelect={styleSelect}
                />
            ) : (
                <Select
                    className={className}
                    style={styles.select}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={changeSelect}
                    options={options}
                    isMulti={isMulti}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default function Tag({ selected, setSelected, styleSelect }) {
    const backgroundColor = styleSelect?.(selected?.label) ?? "grey";
    return (
        <div style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-around",
            padding: "0.1em",
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
            borderRadius: "4px",
            color: "white",
            marginRight: "20px",
            marginLeft: "4px",
            marginBottom: "8px"
        }}>
            {selected}
            <button
                style={{...}}
                onClick={() => setSelected(null)}
            >x</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I really don't understand why is it not working since `dish.taste` returns me "Medium", `dish.comment` returns me 5, `dish.trust` give me 1.

What's wrong with my Dropdown and/or Tag component?

Comment: There is something wrong with your verification. `Array.map` always return array.

Comment: Hi, dish.map((e) => e.menu) returns me "mycontent...." Is it wrong to verify  my array is not empty like this  !== ?

Comment: If you want to check emptyness of array use `Array.length === 0`

Comment: @BrunoPolo, I have added `defaultValue={COMMENT.find((t) => t.label === dish.comment)}` but in my database, `dish.comment` is an integer (0,...10). I tried to do 
`defaultValue={COMMENT.find((t) => t.label === (dish.comment).toString())}` but not working either. Do you have an idea ? With your code my verification works well, but the problem still there for TASTE and COMMENT

Comment: @BrunoPolo, I just saw that t.label is a string and dish.comment is any []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there should be the main problem:

```
<Dropdown
  defaultValue={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === dish.taste)}
/>
```

With this defaultValue prop you are only setting the value once, when the dropdown renders. The **dish.taste** can not be defined at that time if you retrieve its value through an async request. What you should do instead is adding a useEffect that sets the right value of the dropdown only after it has defined the dish.taste value. So:

```
const [valueDropdown, setValueDropdown] = React.useState(null);

useEffect(() => { 
 // here you are running this useEffect each time the dish state changes
 if(dish?.taste){ //checks if taste exists
  setValueDropdown(TASTE.find((t) => t.label === dish.taste));
 }
}, [dish]);
```

Now, instead of passing to the dropdown the defaultValue you should pass two new props: the **value** and the **setValue**:

```
<Dropdown
  value={valueDropdown}
  setValue={setValueDropdown}
/>
```

Lastly, with the change of the props you should also update them inside the Dropdown component and remove the state definition inside that component:

```
export default function CustomDropdown({
  style,
  options,
  styleSelect,
  value : selected,
  setValue : setSelected
}) {
// remove the line const [selected, setSelected] = useState(defaultValue);
....other logic
}
```

Comment: Hi, @HakimAbdelcadir, 
 `if(dish?.taste){ setValueDropdown(TASTE.find((t) => t.label === dish.taste));} }, [dish]);` do I need to put it inside my axios request: `useEffect(() => {axios.post(...))}` so it will be 2 dependecies : `useEffect(()=> {axios.post(..) if(dish?.taste) {...} }, [dishId, dish ]` Or I have to put it in 2 separate useEffect?

Comment: 2 separate useEffect

Comment: Ok, And for the <Checkboxe > would it be the same thing ?

Comment: Yeah the same thing

Comment: I tried to apply what you've written, I can display the defaultValue, but for some reason, I'm not able reselect antother choice, once I click on the cross to deselect the default value, I get an empty value for my dropdown whatever the choice I made. I'll edit my post so you can understand better

Comment: From the code I can see that you didn't follow all the steps for the checkbox. That's why they are not working (I would suggest you to try to understand what I've written beside from the code so that you better understand what is missing in the checkbox). For the other problem you have, I tried my steps on the codesandbox you linked and the deselection perfectly works for both the checkbox and the dropdown so if you still have that problem you should probably update the codesandbox and create another post because it's a different problem from the one on the title and description.

Comment: The given code is working, because it works very well for my local json. But when I tried to use my data from the api using axios.post then it's not working... That's why I'm opening this issue @HakimAbdelcadir

Comment: In the checkbox the problem is that you are still passing directly dish.trust to the Checkbox component. You need to create a proper state as you did for the taste and updating the state inside the useEffect. Lastly, inside the Checkbox function you need to remove the state and instead using the value and setValue that you receive as props.

Comment: Hi, please is it possible to take a look at my (weird) [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72886781/i-have-a-weird-issue-with-react-select-pressing-on-enter-resets-me-all-the-othe), I've never seen this thing happening...

Answer (score 2):

A possible fix:

```
<Dropdown
    style={styles.select}
    options={TASTE}
    defaultValue={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === dish.find((d) => d.id === dishId))}
    isMulti={true}
/>
```

The other part I could not undestand what you're trying to do, but it is wrong. As Cristiano replyied, you are comparing different types using `!==`, so it will never be a true condition. Maybe use the same fix as above?

`(dish.find((d) => d.id === dishId).menu !== "")`

**EDIT AND REEDIT**

Given more information, this could fix:

```
export default function MenuItemDisplay() {
...
    const [dish, setDish] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post(url, { dishId })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                // make your dish variable not array
                setDish(res.data.dishes[0])
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [dishId]);

    const TASTE = [
        { label: "Good", value: "Good" },
        { label: "Medium", value: "Medium" },
        { label: "Bad", value: "Bad" }
    ];

    if (!dish) {
        return (
            <div>Loading</div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Dropdown
                style={styles.select}
                options={TASTE}
                // remove map cuz it is not array
                defaultValue={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === dish.taste)}
                isMulti={true}
            />
            {/* remove map cuz it is not array */}
            {dish.menu !== "") ?
                <div>
                    Menu
                    <div >
                        {question.map((e) => e.menu)}
                    </div>
                </div>
                : ""
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: it's not working, I  think I don't need the id check since I'm already in dishes/:id. For instance, the returned json for `dishId=1` returns me : `[{ "taste": "Medium", "description" :"some description"...}]`

Comment: hmmmm ok... so i'll edit my answer

Comment: @Zokulko see if this works

Comment: it's not working, iI have the same contentwith my old code- (i.e using `setDish(res.data.dishes)`, maybe it could be the typeof `dish.taste` string or int ??

Comment: made some changes. Please note `const [dish, setDish] = useState(null)`, `setDish(res.data.dishes[0])` and the `if (!dish) {` statement.

Comment: Do I need to add `if (!dish){`  in the `useEfect` ?

Comment: It is outside useEffect. This is to make your first render of `<Dropdown />` to actually have the `dish` variable set.

Comment: Mmm would it be the same if inside my Dropdown I do : <Dropdown ...t.label===dish?.taste >?

Comment: Can you provide sample project in codepen?

Comment: I've added it, but I didn't put my url for confidential purposes...

Comment: With your code my verification works well, but the problem still there for TASTE and COMMENT (i've added it, in the issue)

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string (t.label) using === operator with array (result of dish.map) in defaultValue definition.

Try to change it.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

I think the issue is simply that that `defaultValue` prop of a React component is expected to exist when the component mounts and never change. It's the ***default value*** when the component mounts. The code in your example is comparing an element in the `TASTE` array against the initial `dish` state, which is an array but accessed as an object. `dish.taste` of `[]` is undefined.

## Solutions

### Uncontrolled Component

If you want the `Dropdown` component to remain an uncontrolled component then it should be conditionally rendered only when the `dish` state has been initialized by the `useEffect` hook and the POST request.

```
const [dish, setDish] = useState(); // initially undefined

useEffect(() => {
  axios.post(url, { dishId })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      setDish(res.data.dishes[0]);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}, [dishId]);

...

{dish.taste && ( // conditionally render the dropdown
  <Dropdown
    style={styles.select}
    options={TASTE}
    defaultValue={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === dish.taste)}
    isMulti
  />
)}
```

### Controlled Component

If you want the `Dropdown` component to be controlled, then use the (*likely*) `value` prop instead. It's meant to be changed during the life of the component.

```
const [dish, setDish] = useState(); // initially undefined

useEffect(() => {
  axios.post(url, { dishId })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      setDish(res.data.dishes[0]);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}, [dishId]);

...

<Dropdown
  style={styles.select}
  options={TASTE}
  value={TASTE.find((t) => t.label === dish.taste)} // use value prop
  isMulti
/>
```

Comment: I've finally managed to do my Dropdown not the same way as yours, but still stuck with checkboxe. I'm not able to controll the state

Comment: @Zokulko From what I can see of your code snippet it's because you've declared `Checkbox` inside the `MenuItemDisplay` component. Each time `MenuItemDisplay` renders for any reason, the `Checkbox` component is *redeclared*, unmounting any rendered instance and mounts a new instance with the initial `checked` state true. Move `Checkbox` component declaration *outside* of `MenuItemDisplay` on its own. The `Checkbox` component has a similar controlled vs uncontrolled issue. It uses the `defaultChecked` prop, but then also supplies an `onChange` handler. I don't see where `checked` is used.

Comment: I use the checked [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-form-x8vyi4?file=/src/MenuItemDisplay.jsx)

Comment: can you help me with this [issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72736330/14430938) and [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72686224/14430938), [issue3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72839501/14430938) please?

Comment: Hi, please is it possible to take a look at my (weird) [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72886781/i-have-a-weird-issue-with-react-select-pressing-on-enter-resets-me-all-the-othe), I've never seen this thing happening...