# Why does my condition disable one of my feature using REACT?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

why by adding  my 2 conditions, in my `<Table data={menus.filter(i => (applyStatus ? true : i.apply !== 1) && (showGood ? true : i.taste !== "Good"))} .../>`, I'm not able to hide my selected rows. Whereas when I do `<Table data={matchData} .../>`, I can select my rows and hide them by clicking on the `Hide` button.

```
 export default function MenuDisplay() {
      const { menuId } = useParams();
      const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
      const [hidden, setHidden] = useState({});
      const [menus, setMenus]=useState([])
      const [showGood, setShowGood] = useState(false);
      const [applyStatus, setApplyStatus] = useState(false);
    
      if (menus.apply === 0) {
        setApplyStatus(true)
    }
    if (menus.apply === 1) {
      setApplyStatus(false)
    }
    
      useEffect (() => {
        axios.post("",{menuId:parseInt(menuId)})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setMenus(res.data.menus)
                
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [menuId]);
    
    useEffect (() => {
      const GoodMenus = menus.filter((i) => i.taste === "Good");
      const restOfMenus = menus.filter((i) => i.taste !== "Good");      
      setMenus([...GoodMenus, ...restOfMenus]);
    }, [menus]);
    
    
      // If any row is selected, the button should be in the Apply state
      // else it should be in the Cancel state
      const buttonMode = Object.values(selected).some((isSelected) => isSelected)
        ? "apply"
        : "cancel";
    
      const rowSelectHandler = (id) => (checked) => {
        setSelected((selected) => ({
          ...selected,
          [id]: checked
        }));
      };
    
      const handleClick = () => {
        if (buttonMode === "apply") {
          // Hide currently selected items
          const currentlySelected = {};
          Object.entries(selected).forEach(([id, isSelected]) => {
            if (isSelected) {
              currentlySelected[id] = isSelected;
            }
          });
          setHidden({ ...hidden, ...currentlySelected });
    
          // Clear all selection
          const newSelected = {};
          Object.keys(selected).forEach((id) => {
            newSelected[id] = false;
          });
          setSelected(newSelected);
        } else {
          // Select all currently hidden items
          const currentlyHidden = {};
          Object.entries(hidden).forEach(([id, isHidden]) => {
            if (isHidden) {
              currentlyHidden[id] = isHidden;
            }
          });
          setSelected({ ...selected, ...currentlyHidden });
    
          // Clear all hidden items
          const newHidden = {};
          Object.keys(hidden).forEach((id) => {
            newHidden[id] = false;
          });
          setHidden(newHidden);
        }
      };
    
      const matchData = (
        menus.filter(({ _id }) => {
        return !hidden[_id];
      });
    
      const getRowProps = (row) => {
        return {
          style: {
            backgroundColor: selected[row.values.id] ? "lightgrey" : "white"
          }
        };
      };
    
      const data = [
        {
          Header: "id",
          accessor: (row) => row._id
        },
        {
          Header: "Name",
          accessor: (row) => (
            <Link to={{ pathname: `/menu/${menuId}/${row._id}` }}>{row.name}</Link>
          )
        },
        {
          Header: "Description",
          //check current row is in hidden rows or not
          accessor: (row) => row.description
        },
        {
          Header: "Dishes",
          //check current row is in hidden rows or not
          accessor: (row) => row.dishes,
          id: "dishes",
          Cell: ({ value }) => value && Object.values(value[0]).join(", ")
        },
        {
          Header: "Status",
          accessor: (row) => row.status
        },
        {
          Header: "Show",
          accessor: (row) => (
            <Toggle
              value={selected[row._id]}
              onChange={rowSelectHandler(row._id)}
            />
          )
        }
      ];
    
      const initialState = {
        sortBy: [
          { desc: false, id: "id" },
          { desc: false, id: "description" }
        ],
        hiddenColumns: ["dishes", "id"]
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
            {buttonMode === "cancel" ? "Cancel" : "Apply"}
          </button>
          show good
          <Toggle value = {showGood} onChange={() => setShowGood(!showGood)} />
          <Table
            data={menus.filter(i => (applyStatus ? true : i.apply !== 1) && (showGood ? true : i.taste !== "Good"))}
            initialState={initialState}
            withCellBorder
            withRowBorder
            withSorting
            withPagination
            rowProps={getRowProps}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Here my json from my api for `menuId:1`:

```
 [
      {
        "menuId": 1,
        "_id": "123ml66",
        "name": "Pea Soup",
        "description": "Creamy pea soup topped with melted cheese and sourdough croutons.",
        "dishes": [
          {
            "meat": "N/A",
            "vegetables": "pea"
          }
        ],
        "taste": "Good",
        "comments": "3/4",
        "price": "Low",
        "availability": 0,
        "trust": 1,
        "status": "Pending",
        "apply": 1
      },
      //...other data   
   
    ]
```

Comment: `useEffect(() => {  const GoodMenus = //   setMenus([... ]) }, [menus])`   This is not good, what are you trying to do here?.

Comment: It's from my previous [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72669743/14430938), trying to make a toggle  component in order to see the validated status that are not displayed by default.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your issue, but you have some logic issues with your `useEffect` here.

```
useEffect (() => {
  axios.post("",{menuId:parseInt(menuId)})
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        setMenus(res.data.menus)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
, [menuId]);
    
useEffect (() => {
  const GoodMenus = menus.filter((i) => i.taste === "Good");
  const restOfMenus = menus.filter((i) => i.taste !== "Good");      
  setMenus([...GoodMenus, ...restOfMenus]);
}, [menus]);
```

Now in the above the first `useEffect` seems good, your using `axios` to fetch some data, so it's certainly an effect.  You have even set the dependancy array, that's good too, `menuId` is part of the effect.

The second `useEffect` is just wrong, first it's not an effect, and seems totally poinless to use one.  Also a `useMemo` wouldn't make much sense here, in case people are wondering.  The dependancy here is also wrong, because your calling `setMenus` here, this means the dependancy is depending on something your going to change.  I'm suprised this is not causing you a stack overflow, but I assume React has a check for this.

The solution though is pretty easy, just use the one `effect`.

eg.

```
useEffect (() => {
  axios.post("",{menuId:parseInt(menuId)})
    .then(res => {
        const menus = res.data.menus; 
        setMenus([
           ...menus.filter((i) => i.taste === "Good"),
           ...menus.filter((i) => i.taste !== "Good")
        ])
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
, [menuId]);
```

Comment: I still have the same issue, i.e clicking on my button under my `Show` column,  and then on `Hide` button but my row is not hidden... If I do : `<Table data={matchData} .../>`, then it's working otherwise adding my condition `Table data={menus.filter(i => (applyStatus ? true : i.apply !== 1) && (showGood ? true : i.taste !== "Good"))} .../>` it's not working

Comment: if you can also help me with this [bounty issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72736330/react-why-are-my-dropdowns-filters-not-working) please